# Making RabbitMQ listen only to the loopback interface?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

How do I instruct the RabbitMQ processes (`epmd` and `beam.smp`) to listen only to the loopback interface (`127.0.0.1`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can - edit your /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf and add the line:

NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1

you also probably want to add:

NODENAME=rabbit@localhost

which will set your node to listen on localhost.