# Why does rabbitmq listen on port 43411?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, erlang, rabbitmq

I can't for the life of me get it to bind to 127.0.0.1:43411 instead of 0.0.0.0:43411. Any ideas?

```
beam.smp  18538   rabbitmq   10u     IPv4    5797637      0t0        TCP *:43411 (LISTEN)
```

Rabbitmq had a few ports open, [Making RabbitMQ listen only to the loopback interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145137/making-rabbitmq-listen-only-to-the-loopback-interface) helped me bind some of them to loopback but this last one is persistent.

Comment: I think this can help you: [How do I make RabbitMQ listen only to localhost?][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/235669/how-do-i-make-rabbitmq-listen-only-to-localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this port is configured with:

> [{kernel, [{inet_dist_use_interface, {127, 0, 0, 1}}]}].

in config file